# Visual Studio tool tip / pop-up font change?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]Does anybody  know how to change the pop-ups font in Visual Studio ?
I need fixed size fonts and I spent already countless time browsing.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are the pop-ups that you're referring to?

Comment: I added a picture, it's from the main editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are called Tooltips, not pop-ups. And yes, you can change their font settings.

- Go to **Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors**.
- From the drop-down menu, select **Editor Tooltip**:

  [image: Fonts and Colors]
- Change the font settings as you wish and click **OK**.

### Before:

[image: Before]

### After:

[image: After]